# Two database changes under the same variable

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the code:

```
 ...SOME CODE HERE...
//inserting data order
$order = "UPDATE  `database`.`table` SET  `status_client` =  'PRELUAT' WHERE  `flux_receptie`.`id` =$res";
$order = "UPDATE  `database`.`table` SET  `status_client` =  'PRELUAT' WHERE  `flux_receptie`.`id` =$res";

//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
...SOME CODE HERE...
```

Ignore the DB command because it will be modified. My question is that if I can use `$order` for two database commands? Will `$result = mysql_query($order);` work properly? 
Thanks friends! :)

Answer (score 0):

No.

You are redefining `$order` in the second line, so the first time you set `$order` does not do anything. You will have to make two separate queries or combine them into a single MySQL statement.

By default, you are also simply not allowed to execute two queries at once for security purposes (as someone could inject a MySQL command in the middle of yours that does something nefarious). For example. setting `$order` to:

```
`UPDATE `table` SET `column`='value' WHERE (condition); UPDATE `table2` SET `column2`='value2' WHERE (condition2);
```

would not work either.

Comment: Ok I got the idea. So I should use $result = mysql_query($order); and $result = mysql_query($order1); as two separate queries?

Comment: That would work! Make sure to set the values returned to two separate variables if you wanted to use `result` for either.

Comment: A, ok thank you very much. I will test it ASAP and I will bring updates.

Comment: And if I have an IF variable? How will it be? if($result){
 echo "";
} else {
 echo "";
}

Comment: @BogdanConstantinescu please update your original question or better yet try and google and find the answer yourself, many people on SO will not enjoy being providers of free advice to people who don't make an effort to solve their problems themselves before asking for community help, cheers

Answer (score 0):

(following on from Nathans answer, and the comments to this)

To make two queries, simply structure:

```
//inserting data order
$order1 = "UPDATE  `database`.`table` SET  `status_client` =  'PRELUAT' WHERE  `flux_receptie`.`id` =$res";
$order2 = "UPDATE  `database`.`table` SET  `status_client` =  'PRELUAT' WHERE  `flux_receptie`.`id` =$res";

//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query($order1);  //order executes
$resultTwo = mysql_query($order2);
```

This will execute both orders as defined in the variable string. I highly recommend exploring OOP MySQL with MySQLi or PDO methodology. Google it :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Will do that! :)